# Couldnt launch the emulator Kony IDE

Tags: temenos-quantum

I could run the simple form on android emulator :
When I try to run on emulator , following I am getting ::

init:

emu:
     [echo] emulator.dir: C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools
     [echo] emu loc: C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
     [echo] apk.file: F:\KonyTraining\temp\TestApp1\build\luaandroid\dist\luavmandroid.apk
     [echo] appID: TestApp1
     [echo] avdname: konyavdmap
     [echo] cmd args: 
     [echo] android package name : com.orgname.TestApp1
     [echo] web.selected : false
     [echo] Jetty.IP : 10.15.102.56
     [echo] Jetty.Port : 8888
     [echo] AVD name is konyavdmap
[exec-script] The system cannot find the path specified.
[exec-script] Result: 255

Please note the android sdk path and kony path

Kony is installed at : C:\Program Files\Kony
Android SDK is installed at : C:\Program Files\Android\sdk

Comment: Have you checked Window->Preference->Android Home? Is it the right path?

Comment: Sometimes, it may complain if the folder path contains space " ". In this case "Program Files" or "Kony Android SDK" may be the culprit.